# Из списка вытащить e-mail

Tags: python, list, type-error

Имеется список со словами, необходимо вернуть электронный адрес.
Условия прописал, но выпадает ошибка TypeError:

> list indices must be integers or slices, not str

код:

```
text = "мое мыло hot@mail.ru"
text = text.split()
for word in text:
    if text[word].count("@") == 1 and text[word][0] != "@" and text[word].count(".") > 0 and text[word].rfind(".") > text[word].find("@"):
        print(word)
```

Comment: Операция вида `строка[индекс]` вытаскивает символ из строки по указанному индексу, при этом индекс обязан быть числом, потому что это позиция символа в строке. У вас же `word` не число, а строка, поэтому выражение `text[word]` является бессмысленным

Comment: Гм... а регуляркой не пробовали?

Comment: не проходил пока что эти библиотеки)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь обратиться к элементам списка text по строковому индексу word, вместо целочисленного. В цикле for переменная word является элементом списка text, а не индексом

```
text = "мое мыло hot@mail.ru"
text = text.split()

for i in range(len(text)):
  word = text[i]
  if word.count("@") == 1 and word[0] != "@" and word.count(".") > 0 and word.rfind(".") > word.find("@"):
    print(word)
```

Можно так же использовать регулярные выражение

```
import re

text = "мое мыло hot@mail.ru"
email = re.findall(r'\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z|a-z]{2,}\b', text)

if email:
    print(email[0])
```

Comment: ну нельзя городить такие условия проверки. мало того, что громоздко, так еще не все варианты учитываются, некоторые валидные адреса не выявляются и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: Чудесно, нельзя городить!? Человек написал сам код, сказал про ошибку - я обьяснил ошибку и исправил ее, без оптимизации кода. Что не так!?

Comment: Конечно можно использовать регулярки или по другому решить вопрос)Вопрос то стоял в другом

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, стараюсь решать согласно пройденному материалу

Comment: попробовал написать функцию с этим кодом и через фильтр вернуть результат, но почему то возвращает пустой список, """def is_mail(text):     return re.findall(r'\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z|a-z]{2,}\b', text)   result = filter(is_mail, text)  print(result)"""

Comment: @sLoNcE Вот зачем вы заменили одну строку кода `for word in text:` на две строки `for i in range(len(text)):
  word = text[i]`? Вы ведь дальше `i` всё-равно нигде не используете.